# What is the migration path for the LUIS authoring API and CLI?

Tags: botframework

after the latest change in the LUIS portal it is no longer possible to import an app that is downloaded from the portal, using the LUIS CLI. The structure of the exported file is different from the old portal. Maybe the portal is already using V3 API's?
This migration path to V3 is very confusing as the authoring API's seem to be in preview state.
Can you please help me out with a clear timeline and migration path?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-migration-authoring-entities
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-migration-api-v3
https://www.luis.ai/home
https://previous.luis.ai/home

Comment: can you elaborate on what issues you are running into when you try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-migration-api-v3? You can also refer to a similar issue in https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/52422.

Comment: Exporting an existing app in JSON  from https://eu.luis.ai/ and importing it with 'luis import application' or 'luis import version' fails. If the same app is exported from https://previous.eu.luis.ai/ these commands succeed.